# Aggregate count of various fields in document based off condition

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm looking to be able to get certain values and get the count of how many times those values are in a collection based off which key has a certain id. For instance, here's an example of a single document from a collection of Game Logs

```
{
    "_id": "5af88940b73b2936dcb6dfdb",
    "date": "2018-05-13T18:51:44.548Z",
    "playerOne": "5af888d0b73b2936dcb6dfd3",
    "playerOneThrew": "Scissors",
    "playerTwo": "5af88918b73b2936dcb6dfd7",
    "playerTwoThrew": "Rock",
    "winner": "5af88918b73b2936dcb6dfd7",
     "__v": 0
}
```

I'm looking to be able to query based off a Players ID (could be playerOne or could be playerTwo) and pull back the hand that player threw for each match. Essentially I'm looking to be able to get a total count of all hands thrown (rock, paper, scissors) for all games by Players ID.

Is there a way to aggregate a count for each "thrown hand" value for all documents in a collection and return something like

```
{
    "player": "5af888d0b73b2936dcb6dfd3",
    "Rock": 3,
    "Paper": 6,
    "Scissors": 12
}
```

My thoughts are to set a variable based on which id matches playerOne || playerTwo then use that variable in switch statement where I aggregate the count of "rock", "paper", "scissors". Problem is I'm new to using MongoDB and I'm having difficulty understanding the proper syntax for a query like this.

Here's where I'm currently at

```
GameLogs.aggregate(
  [
    {
      $let: {
        vars: {
          playerThrew: {
            $cond: {
              if: {
                $eq: { playerOne: id },
              }
              }, then: playerOneThrew, else: playerTwoThrew
            }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $switch: {
        branches: [
          { case: { $eq: 'Rock' }, then: { $count: 'Rock' } },
          { case: { $eq: 'Paper' }, then: { $count: 'Paper' } },
          { case: { $eq: 'Scissors' }, then: { $count: 'Scissors' } },
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
)
```

Psuedocode

```
if playerOne == id
  playerThrew = playerOneThrows
else if playerTwo == id
  playerThrew = playerTwoThrows

switch playerThrew {
  case 'rock':
    rockCount++
    break
  case 'paper':
    paperCount++
    break
  case 'scissors':
    scissorsCount++
    break
}

return {
  player_id: id,
  rock: rockCount,
  paper: paperCount,
  scissors: scissorCount
}
```

Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Radosław Miernik's answer is good, but there is still a `$match` required, as OP wants to fetch data for a specific player only.

Lets say `playerId` is the `_id` of the player whose data is needed.

Below code should work, and give expected results

```
collection.aggregate([
  {$project: {
    player: [
      {id: '$playerOne', threw: '$playerOneThrew'},
      {id: '$playerTwo', threw: '$playerTwoThrew'}
    ],
  }},
  {$unwind: '$player'},
  {$match : { 
    "player.id" : playerId 
  }},
  {$group: {
    _id: '$player.id',
    player : {$first : "$player.id},
    Paper:    {$sum: {$cond: [{$eq: ['$player.threw', 'Paper'   ]}, 1, 0]}},
    Rock:     {$sum: {$cond: [{$eq: ['$player.threw', 'Rock'    ]}, 1, 0]}},
    Scissors: {$sum: {$cond: [{$eq: ['$player.threw', 'Scissors']}, 1, 0]}}
  }}
])
```

This will give the exact result which you are looking for, plus an extra `_id` field.

```
{
    "_id": "5af888d0b73b2936dcb6dfd3",
    "player": "5af888d0b73b2936dcb6dfd3",
    "Rock": 3,
    "Paper": 6,
    "Scissors": 12
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split each of your docs into two normalised ones and then group them easily:

```
collection.aggregate([
  {$match: {
    $or: [
      {playerOne: playerId},
      {playerTwo: playerId}
    ]
  },
  {$project: {
    player: [
      {id: '$playerOne', threw: '$playerOneThrew'},
      {id: '$playerTwo', threw: '$playerTwoThrew'}
    ],
  }},
  {$unwind: '$player'},
  {$match: {'player.id': playerId},
  {$group: {
    _id: '$player.id',
    Paper:    {$sum: {$cond: [{$eq: ['$player.threw', 'Paper'   ]}, 1, 0]}},
    Rock:     {$sum: {$cond: [{$eq: ['$player.threw', 'Rock'    ]}, 1, 0]}},
    Scissors: {$sum: {$cond: [{$eq: ['$player.threw', 'Scissors']}, 1, 0]}}
  }}
])
```

**EDIT:** Added `$match` stages to efficiently filter scores only for given player.